# Flutter screen "magnification" for tablet as a blanket operation over already established mobile screen layout

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Wondering if there is a way to blanket "magnify" an entire screen layout including all widgets & properties such as text scaling etc.

I have discovered there are a few screens which can do best as a simple magnification instead of a completely different layout when going from mobile to tablet sizes. Is there a way to shortcut this as opposed to totally different layouts?

The end goal would be nearly exact same layout but every element on tablet is larger.

Comment: This seems like an odd idea :D But, assuming you know what you're doing, what about aspect ratio? If your mobile layout works on vertical 9:16 you cannot just scale it to fit on 16:9 horizontal tablet.

Comment: If you're open to suggestions, tweaking just text scale factor seems to be enough for most apps